# Data transform introducing a bias in kriged geostatistical model?

Tags: data-transformation, bias, geostatistics

I am kriging a 3D geospatial model of saturation data. There is water saturation ($SWT$), gas saturation ($SGT$) and oil saturation ($SOT$). A constraint is that the saturations must add up to one. ($SWT + SGT + SOT = 1$). I want models of SWT and SGT and don't really care about the oil saturation, but I do need $SWT + SGT <= 1$ to be satisfied.

I have a kriged model of water saturation ($SWT$). I kriged a model of $SGT$, but in some small areas the kriged models of $SWT + SGT > 1$.

My idea was to keep the kriged model of $SWT$, and standardize the $SGT$ and $SOT$ by the total hydrocarbon saturation, $SHT = 1 - SWT$:

$SGT_{standardized}=SGT/{(1-SWT)}$

$SOT_{standardized}=1-SGT_{standardized}$

I would then krige a model of $SGT_{standardized}$.

Then, I need to back transform:

$SGT = SGT_{standardized}(1-SWT)$

This does seem to ensure that I get a geostatistical model such that $SWT + SGT <= 1$. However, I am worried this transformation may introduce some bias?

If I have the average of the SGT data:

$E[SGT] = x$

And the average of the standardized SGT is:

$E[SGT_{standardized}] = y$

Now, what if I back transform the average of the standardized SGT?

$y(1-E[SWT])\neq x$

It is close to x, but not equal to x. Does that mean the transform is biased? Or that my kriged estimate of $SGT$ would be biased?